# iPhone recent calls list reappears after clear

Tags: bug, iphone, call, phone.app

Today I've cleared my recent calls list about 6 times, and it keeps coming back. What gives?

Comment: What version of iOS are you running?

Comment: @grgarside iOS9 but it did it on iOS8 as well.

Comment: Works as expected on my iPhone 6 iOS 9.0.  Does the problem persist after a hard reset?

Answer (score -2):

it's a bug. not only Facetime on iPhone but iMac also. Apple have no solution!